# Error when I try to open a .dat file

Tags: c, matlab

I have a problem when I try to open a .dat file in a c code. Probably the error I made will be very obvious to some of you but I can't find it so I ask for your help.
The point of my code is to open the .dat file which contains 12.000.000 double numbers and store it in a cuDoubleComplex array which size will be 6.000.000 variables (the even variables of the .dat represents the real part and the odd variables the imaginary (I mean the order, not the value of the variable))

Here is an extract of my code:

```
#include "cuComplex.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 12000000; //12.000.000
    int lse = n / 2;
    double *data = (double *)malloc(12000000 * sizeof(double));
    double *data2 = (double *)malloc(12000000 * sizeof(double));
    FILE *f, *f2;
    cuDoubleComplex *se, *se2;

    f = fopen("ref_PRI20.dat", "r");
    fread(data, sizeof(double), n, f);
    fclose(f);

    f2 = fopen("surv_PRI20.dat", "r");
    fread(data2, sizeof(double), n, f2);
    fclose(f2);


    for (int a = 0; a < n; a++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", data2[a]);
    }


    se = (cuDoubleComplex*)malloc(lse * sizeof(cuDoubleComplex));
    se2 = (cuDoubleComplex*)malloc(lse * sizeof(cuDoubleComplex));
    for (int a = 0; a<n / 2; a++)
    {
        se[a].x = data[2 * a];
        se[a].y = data[2 * a + 1];
        se2[a].x = data2[2 * a];
        se2[a].y = data2[2 * a + 1];
    }  
free(data);
free(data2);

}
```

I have added the printf lines and bucle just to check and all I get is "0,0000" as a value. Although when I continue with the programm the se and se2 arrays seems to get random values.
I know the size of the arrays is huge but I need to work with that amount of data.

I also have tried to work in matlab and I had no mistakes in there. This is the code that I used in matlab and everything was fine so I guess there is no problem with the .dat files but only with my code.

```
f = fopen ("ref_PRI20.dat", 'r');

Data = fread (f, 12e6, 'double');
fclose (f);

dat=(Data(1:2:end)+1i*Data(2:2:end)).';
```

Here's a scan of the input data so you can see the format. I hope it will help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJlBP.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I have read the post that you linked but honestly I don't know how that could help me. If you are sure that is the solution, could you help me to apply it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi @user3121023, I have just checked everything you said and it seems to be fine.

Comment: regarding: `#include <iostream>`   that header file is for C++, not C.  Suggest you remove that statement.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `fread()`, always compare the returned value with the third parameter, to assure all the desired data was read.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), 1)  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making understanding, debug, etc more difficult.

Comment: trying to read 12000000*sizeof(double) bytes at the same pass is not a good idea.  It will take a bit longer, but much better to input one double value at a time.  BTW: what is separating those values in the input files? Anything other than a single space char will be a problem.  BTW: the posted code is expecting NO separator between the double values.  This implies that the file is a BINARY file.  So the 'mode' parameter to `fopen()` (for portability) should be: "rb"

Comment: please post the contents of the header file: `cuComplex.h`

Comment: Now I could do all the checks that you said and nothing failed at that point. Thanks anyway, I will follow your advise.

Comment: On the other, hand the separating value when I open the .dat with a text reader file are commas, any idea? I also had change the mode for the fopen as suggested but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: If the input file values are separated by commas, are the numbers readable?  If so, the `fread()` is not the right way to input the values and the file is NOT a binary file.  If separated by commas, then the input needs to have each value extracted so the commas are not placed into the data arrays.   Please post some sample input from the input file(s)

Comment: @user3629249 I'm sorry for the late response, now I will try the options that are suggested and I'll tell you the results. For now I will update the question with a scan of the input file.

Comment: @user3629249 as you and other user suggested my problem was solved when I changed the freads for fscanf, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No error checking on the original code for malloc or fopen.
Since a comment said the file was opened in a text reader and had commas between values, fscanf should be used to input the values instead of fread.
Since the values must be scanned one at a time there isn't a need for the data or data2 pointers.
Could not compile this as I don't have cuComplex.h

```
#include "cuComplex.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 12000000; //12.000.000
    int lse = n / 2;
    FILE *f, *f2;
    cuDoubleComplex *se, *se2;

    f = fopen("ref_PRI20.dat", "r");

    f2 = fopen("surv_PRI20.dat", "r");

    se = malloc(lse * sizeof(cuDoubleComplex));
    se2 = malloc(lse * sizeof(cuDoubleComplex));
    for (int a = 0; a < lse; a++)
    {
        if ( 1 != fscanf ( f, "%lf ,", &se[a * 2].x])) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "could not scan double\n");
            break;
        }
        if ( 1 != fscanf ( f, "%lf ,", &se[a * 2 + 1].y)) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "could not scan double\n");
            break;
        }
        if ( 1 != fscanf ( f2, "%lf ,", &se2[a * 2].x)) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "could not scan double\n");
            break;
        }
        if ( 1 != fscanf ( f2, "%lf ,", &se2[a * 2 + 1].y)) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "could not scan double\n");
            break;
        }
    }  
    fclose(f);
    fclose(f2);
    free ( se);
    free ( se2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi and before anything I'm sorry for the late response. You are right, my problem was completely solved when I changed the fread for fscanf, thank so much.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. properly checks for and handles errors
3. reads the data directly into the struct.
4. Did not use the cuComplex.h file as that was not available.
5. avoided the use of 'magic' numbers
6. although the 'b' is not necessary in linux/unix, properly set the open mode to BINARY READ
7. documented why each header file is included.
8. eliminated all unnecessary variables and unnecessary calls to `malloc()`
9. eliminated all unnecessary data copying.
10. It may be desirable to read the data in a loop, using a 'moving window' until a 12000000 doubles are read.  I'll let you add that feature, if necessary.

And now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // fopen(), fread(), printf(), fprintf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, malloc(), free()


#define N 12000000

struct cuDoubleComplex
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct cuDoubleComplex *data = malloc( (N>>1) * sizeof(double));
    if( !data )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    struct cuDoubleComplex *data2 = malloc( (N>>1) * sizeof(double));
    if( !data2 )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    FILE *f = fopen("ref_PRI20.dat", "rb");
    if( !f )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        free( data );
        free( data2 );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    size_t nmemb = fread(data, sizeof(double), N, f);
    if( nmemb != N )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "read of first file only read %lu doubles\n", nmemb );
        free( data );
        free( data2 );
        fclose( f );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    fclose(f);

    FILE *f2 = fopen("surv_PRI20.dat", "rb");
    if( !f2 )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        free( data );
        free( data2 );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    size_t nmemb2 = fread(data2, sizeof(double), N, f2);
    if( nmemb2 != N )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "read of second file only read %lu doubles\n", nmemb2 );
        free( data );
        free( data2 );
        fclose( f2 );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    fclose(f2);

    for (int a = 0; a < N; a++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", data2[a].y);
    }


    free(data);
    free(data2);
} // end function: main
```